# Get specific value from json data in store in variable in Angular 2

Tags: typescript, angular

I am trying to get specific value from json data

### Api

```
approvalPendingRequest(id) {
    return this.http.get('https://localhost:44300/api/apis/GetSubscriptionById/'+ id)
        .subscribe(
        data => this._data = data.json(),
        err => this.logError(err),
        () => console.log()
        );
}
```

### detail

It return data in following formatfrom following I want to save ProductId in a variable ansd then use it.

### Image

[image]

Comment: what does `data.ProductId` returns.

Comment: so store this value in variable.

Comment: data return number of key value attribute how to get productId

Comment: `data.ProductId` should return the product id.

Answer (score 0):

inside callback itself you can save the value as:

```
approvalPendingRequest(id) {
    return this.http.get('https://localhost:44300/api/apis/GetSubscriptionById/'+ id)
       .subscribe((data)=>{
           var prod_id=data.ProductId;
           console.log(prod_id);
       }        
    );
}
```

Hope this helps.